# Overwrite array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, overwrite, unset

How do I overwrite (or unset and then set) an array? Seems like `"array = new_array"` doesn't work.

Comment: Can you please provide a code sample for us to see why `array = new_array` code is not working?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Hm, it seems like the problem wasn't what I thought; my mistake was the following rows, which after all havn't got anything to do with arrays at all:

```
sms.original = eval('(' + data + ')');
sms.messages = sms.original;
```

*sms.original* becomes an object, and then *sms.messages* becomes *sms.original* (I just wanted them to have the same value). The objects contain an array named *items* which was ment to remain static in the *sms.original* object, but when I changed *sms.messages* the original object changed as well. The solution was simple:

```
sms.original = eval('(' + data + ')');
sms.messages = eval('(' + data + ')');
```

Sorry for bothering you, I should have elaborated but the code is splited in multiple files and functions. Thank you guys anyway, now does Guffa's splice technique work for me.

Answer (score 14):

To create an empty array to assign to the variable, you can use the Array constructor:

```
array = new Array();
```

Or you can use an empty array literal:

```
array = [];
```

If you have several references to one array so that you have to empty the actual array object rather than replacing the reference to it, you can do like this:

```
array.splice(0, array.length);
```

Answer (score 4):

**Clearing an array**

http://2ality.com/2012/12/clear-array.html

```
let myArray = [ 1, 2, 3, 4];

myArray = [];
myArray.length = 0;
```

Comment: If you need to clear out an array without breaking the reference, `myArray.length = 0` is what you're looking for!

Answer (score 3):

This should work.

```
array1 = array2;
```

If not, please provide more details.

Comment: I don't think you need to explicitly state array1 = null. If you just update the reference, the garbage collector should recognize an instance that has no references pointing to it.

Comment: No need for two assignments; the second one is enough.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do, but there are a couple of ways to go about resetting an array.

You could just iterate through the existing array and set each index equal to null (or an empty string or 0 or whatever value you consider to be a reset):

```
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
   arr[i] = null;
}
```

You could also just update the existing reference to a new instance of an object:

```
arr = [];
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [Slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

like this -> `array = new_array.slice(0);`